# Why are there my_form_open() Python functions in my QGIS project file?

Tags: pyqgis, function, qgs

I have a project open with 6 layers (MapInfo .tab format), have set the style for each layer and added labels for 1 of them. So for a simple project the .qgs file is about 2000 lines long and among other things I can't quite make sense of there are 6 (duplicate) examples of a Python function `my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature)` in the .qgs file (1 for every layer?). Does anyone know why they are there in the first place and then why would it write out the example 6 times...? the function doesn't have a `return` statement so it wouldn't work anyway

Comment: What version of QGIS is the .qgs file?

Comment: version 2.14.2-Essen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the possibility to add python code to the QGIS attribute forms which will be executed when it opens. To configure it go to the *Fields* tab in the layer properties and change the *Python Init Code* combobox.

If you choose *Provide code in this dialog* you will see the code. As long as this combobox is set to a different entry the code will not be executed. The code which you see is the default template for the code.

N.b. python code does not require a `return` statement to be working.

Comment: ok...the combobox was set to blank for each of my layers but the code was still included - but I get that it's just a template for inserting custom code. I changed it to _Load from external file_, saved and still there in the project file though. It's not too important just trying to understand why these things are there.

Comment: N.b. surely if you're defining a function then it needs to have a return value?

Comment: Once changed, the text should stay there so you don't lose your carefully written code if you temporarily change the combobox. A pull request that will not write the template code to the file would probably be accepted.

concerning return value
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all